# django docker exited with code 0 in request GET or POST

Tags: django, post, docker, get, docker-compose

Good friends, I am developing an application in django 1.11 with docker on windows, recently update the git repository of the project and also made some changes with docker containers.

The problem is that when entering the main page and some other URLS nothing happens, but when I try to login to the administrator, the django container is closed and I do not even get any error by the browser, console or log .

Example:

When I come in here they are fine

GET / 200 OK 
POST / 403 Forbidden 
GET / api / auth / 405 Method not allowed

But when I enter these, without showing any message, close the docker container (proyect_django_1 exited with code 0)

GET / admin No answer 
POST / api / auth / No answer

My docker-compose

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    build: docker/postgres
    volumes:
      - ./docker/data/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=project
  redis:
    image: redis:3.2-alpine
    volumes:
      - ./docker/data/redis:/data
  rabbit:
    image: rabbitmq:3-management-alpine
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=admin
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=admin
  django:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        - REQUIREMENTS=development.txt
    command: python3.6 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8008
    volumes:
      - ./:/code
    working_dir: /code/project
    env_file: ./docker/DevelopmentEnv
    ports:
      - "8008:8008"
    links:
      - db
      - rabbit
      - redis
    depends_on:
      - db

  celeryworker:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        - REQUIREMENTS=development.txt
    working_dir: /code/project
    volumes:
      - ./:/code
    env_file: ./docker/DevelopmentEnv
    links:
      - db
      - rabbit
    command: celery -A config worker -l INFO -Q celery

  frontend:
    image: node:8.4-alpine
    volumes:
      - ./:/code
    working_dir: /code/frontend
    command: ash -c "yarn install --no-bin-links && yarn run build"

  socketio:
    image: node:8.4-alpine
    volumes:
      - ./:/code
    working_dir: /code/sockets
    command: ash -c "yarn install --no-bin-links && yarn start"
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    links:
      - redis
      - django
    depends_on:
      - redis
```

My dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.6.2-alpine3.6
ARG REQUIREMENTS
RUN apk update
RUN apk add postgresql-dev postgresql-client
RUN apk add libffi-dev gcc
RUN apk add musl-dev zlib-dev jpeg-dev
RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps-testing \
    --repository http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing \
    gdal-dev

RUN mkdir /code
ADD ./ /code/
WORKDIR /code
RUN pip3.6 install -r requirements/$REQUIREMENTS
WORKDIR /code/project
```

Comment: Post your Dockerfile and other details

Comment: what command are you running to start the app? There is no CMD section inside your Dockerfile. Your container will exit instantly when running.

Comment: The container if it runs, and it responds to me several urls without problems, but others do not. The command I ran to run all the containers is docker-compose up

Answer (score 1):

You could add `restart: always` to your `django` service definition. This will start a new `django` container if the previous one exits for any reason.

You should be getting some logs about why the process is exiting. Try running `docker inspect <container-name>` to see if there are any clues about why the process exits. There is probably a bug in your Python code triggered by some URLs, and it causes the process to exit.